# Faster PowersRepresentation using IntegerPartitions

Tags: performance-tuning, number-theory

Earlier I posted a question about taking fast integer square roots of known integer perfect squares.

The reason this came up is I was trying to find a faster way of mimicking the PowersRepresentations[] function in Mathematica.

Using IntegerPartitions[] I can speed up this by quite a bit - but then I needed to take the square roots of the output from IntegerPartitions - which ends up costing me about a factor of two or three in speed. Though still a lot faster than using PowersRepresentations[] directly.

For example:

```
n = 8174;
parts = 6;

Length@PowersRepresentations[n, parts, 2] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {1.1861, 31934} *)

Length@IntegerPartitions[n, {parts}, 
   Range[0, IntegerPart[Sqrt[n]]]^2] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.021446, 31934} *)

Length@Round[
   Sqrt[N[
     IntegerPartitions[n, {parts}, 
      Range[0, IntegerPart[Sqrt[n]]]^2]]]] // AbsoluteTiming

(* {0.039502, 31934} *)
```

This might be a silly wish - but is there a way of cutting out the middle man so to speak. I'd like the output of IntegerPartitions[] to be the integers themselves and not their squares. This seems unlikely but does anyone know a workaround or am I destined to have to take the square roots after the fact? Having said this I would think a workaround would be no faster anyway. I'll delete the question if it is asking the impossible.

(Oh, and one thing that puzzles me - why does PowersRepresentations[] run so much faster on a repeat run even if I clear the system cache?)

Comment: Does this only work for second powers?  Or do you get substantial speed up with higher powers as well?

Comment: Integer square root is [sufficiently important](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_square_root) in number theory that there is an undocumented implementation in Mathematica, ``NumberTheory`IntegerSqrt``.  It offers a small speed boost over `IntegerPart@Sqrt`

Comment: @QuantumDot - I wasn't interested in other powers but I just tested it and the speed up is even greater.

Comment: @QuantumDot - I just tested that and it is far slower than Round[Sqrt[N[....

Comment: I got a speed up with:
`n = 8174;
parts = 6;
sqrt = Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, IntegerPart[Sqrt[x]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];
Length@sqrt[IntegerPartitions[n, {parts}, Range[0, sqrt[n]]^2]] // AbsoluteTiming`

Comment: @QuantumDot - Yes that is somewhat faster. Good job.

Comment: @1729taxi Have you looked into the implementation code of `PowersRepresentations`? It's implemented in top-level code, so you may take inspiration from the existing code to modify it to your problem. In your case of `PowersRepresentations[, parts, 2]`, this calls the internal ``NumberTheory`PowersRepresentationsDump`squareRepresentation ``, which is also implemented in top-level code and perhaps you may be able to use the code as inspiration and modify it to output what you want. You will need to run `ClearAttributes[PowersRepresentations, ReadProtected]` and `??PowersRepresentations`,

Comment: @MarcoB - Could you explain a little more. What am I supposed to be seeing when I run those commands?

Comment: @1729taxi I've posted a clarification as an "answer" below, although it doesn't really answer your question, but simply because that way I could more easily include pictures as well.

Answer (score 1):

**This is an extended comment, with pictures.**

`PowersRepresentations` is implemented in top-level code, so you may take inspiration from its existing code and modify it to output what you want. In particular, `PowersRepresentations[.. , .., 2]` calls the internal `` NumberTheory`PowersRepresentationsDump`squareRepresentation ``, which is also implemented in top-level code. Perhaps you may be able to use that code as inspiration and modify it to output what you want.

```
(* The single call below is needed to force the loading of definitions *)
PowersRepresentations[10, 2, 2]; 

(* remove the ReadProtected attribute *)
ClearAttributes[PowersRepresentations, ReadProtected]

(* retrieve the definitions of the function, if any *)
??PowersRepresentations
```

[image: definitions of PowersRepresentations]

Rooting through the above you will notice the following, where I've stripped the `` NumberTheory`PowersRepresentationsDump` ``  for readability:

```
PowersRepresentations[n_Integer?Positive, d_Integer?Positive, 2] := 
 Block[{res}, 
  res = NumberTheory`PowersRepresentationsDump`squareRepresentation[d, n]; 
  res /; FreeQ[res, $Failed]
]
```

This shows that `PowersRepresentations[n, d, 2]`, which seems to be the application of interest to you, reduces to a call to `` NumberTheory`PowersRepresentationsDump`squareRepresentation[d, n] `` (notice the switch in the order of the arguments).

Repeating the same steps, you can dig further into the definition of e.g. `squareRepresentation`, `TaxiCabNumbers`, and other functions that seem to be the actual implementations of the underlying algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll look into this. Ironic there is a function called TaxiCabNumbers when my username is 1729taxi.